# cannot locate symbol "__android_log_write" - Android native logging

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I am trying to log some info from my native code into logcat but I can't seem to get it working. I have searched all over stackoverflow (and other websites).

In my native code I have `#include <android/log.h>`. It fully compiles with no errors. If I don't use the logging at all my native code runs in android.

my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/mylib.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := gmp-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libgmp.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The error I get:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__android_log_write" referenced by <package>`

Lastly, the log I use looks like this:

`__android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "Native tag", "Native text");`

Does anybody know what is going wrong?

Comment: have you added `#define` ? Like  `#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)` ?

Comment: That would not solve anything since that is a preprocessor macro's and will actually compile into the regular `__android_log_write`. However, for being so desperate I have tried it without any good results.

Answer (score 1):

Try `-llog` in your link step. You need the logging library.